# query to to show odd or even values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have warehouse locations that I would like to query and return only odd or even locations. 
My table looks like this:

```
LOCN  AISLE BAY LVL POSN
F0201A1 F02 1   A   1
F0203A2 F02 3   A   2
F0204A3 F02 4   A   3
F0205B1 F02 5   B   1
F0206B2 F02 6   B   2
F0207B3 F02 7   B   3
F0208C1 F02 8   C   1
F0209C2 F02 9   C   2
F0209C3 F02 9   C   3
```

Comment: Please show what rows you are calling "even" and what rows you are calling "odd".

Comment: SELECT * FROM locn_hdr WHERE locn_brcd BETWEEN 'F0201' AND 'F0211' and  lvl in ('A', 'B', 'C') and where (bay) % 2 > 0 order by (bay))

Comment: Fixed the formatting on my post

Comment: @user2668214 Please remove your comment and edit your question with your attempted code.

Answer (score 2):

#### edited to match field name

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE BAY % 2 = 0;
```

returns even number bays.

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE BAY % 2 = 1;
```

returns odd numbered bays.

Comment: Right idea, but probably not the `locn` field because it is a string.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: Original post did not make string `locn` obvious. Hard to say what's even and odd in `locn` string.

Comment: The bay field is the key, if I can get the odd or even numbers on the bay that would give me the results I need

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out:

```
SELECT locn_brcd FROM locn_hdr WHERE locn_brcd BETWEEN 'F0654' AND 'F0679' and  lvl in ('D', 'E', 'F')  and posn in ('1', '2') and mod(bay,2) = 0;

SELECT locn_brcd FROM locn_hdr WHERE locn_brcd BETWEEN 'F0569' AND 'F0580' and  lvl in ('D', 'E', 'F') and mod(bay,2) = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clean. 
Buy I'll assume you have column for numbers that  contain integer (number of street)

Use modulus.

Like this:

`SELECT number FROM locations WHERE number % 2 = 1`